# Camera control without a mod/patch?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

It's possible to change the camera (besides the both that come in the default installation game) without the toca mod/patch? I mean, something like editing some config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - there is no method built into the game to deviate from these two camera angles. Unfortunately without using an unofficial patch/modification there is no way to get anything other than the standard "bumper cam" or *very* close chase cam.